# First server in history was used through Usenet, right?

Tags: networking, webserver, usenet

For some studying and research pupose, I need to know when the first used server was. I tried to google it, but I only got the first **web server** in **1990**.

I know about **ARPA** in **1969**. But as far as I understand, ARPA network was between computers and there were no servers. Although they used the convetion of *server host* and *user host*, still there was no dedicated server. I mean dedicated in a way like high and powerful resouces compared to hosts.

For **Usenet** in **1981**, there were servers. I mean dedicated powerful news servers relativly to users PCs.

If so, **can we say that the first used server was in 1981 (Usenet)?**

Comment: There is no difference between a network of computers and a network of servers, in both cases, considers servers are computers.  Your trying to make a distinction between a computer and a server when there isn't one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the one hand, definitely not. For Usenet in 1981, there *weren't* anything like "dedicated powerful news servers".

Usenet itself is older than Internet and possibly older than ARPAnet; initially the news spools were kept on the same [computer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDP-11) (e.g. a university's Unix system) that everyone logged in to from their local [terminals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VT220) – the same system that employees or students used for mail, text editing, typesetting, and other stuff; so definitely not a "dedicated server". Programs like `rn` used to simply access `/var/spool/news`, and to this day you can have email delivered to `/var/spool/mail/$USER`.

Also, for a long time dial-up [UUCP links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UUCP) were their primary mail & news exchange mechanism, creating a peer-to-peer mesh – the closest thing to "dedicated server" would have been a few popular hosts with a lot of peers, e.g. `decvax`. "Bang paths" (host!host!…!user) come from UUCP. You can find an old news archive at [OldUsenet.](http://olduse.net/)

---

But on the other hand, maybe even earlier than that.

The computers (minicomputers and mainframes) used by companies and universities were *already* significantly more powerful than the average personal computer of that time, with much more memory and disk space, and possibly hosting several dozen user logins at once – acting as a "terminal server". So maybe you could say that servers were born *before* networked hosts. (Disclaimer: I haven't checked actual dates of when things happened.)

---

So I would say that there really isn't a single point in time when someone "invented the server" – I do not know the history well, but it does seem that this sort of thing just gradually evolved.

After all, the [first "web server"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:First_Web_Server.jpg) was merely a NeXT workstation with "do not turn off" written on it. And many people used to run dial-up BBSes off their own PCs, with some more disk space added – those were *dedicated*, but far from "high and powerful".